# Maintain maps current state on server round trip

Tags: geoext

Hopefully a fairly straightforward question...

I have my GeoExt map displayed in a window on my page using a  Ext.Window(...) object.  The page in the background that the map is displayed on needs to do a server round trip when a form on the page is submitted.  Is there a way for the window and map to maintain its state (ie, window size and position & maps current cooridnates, zoom level etc etc).

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it:

Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(new Ext.state.CookieProvider());

and in the window add:

stateId: "themap"

Next question coming soon ;)